# Why we need to write u8NAL first to .h264 file before writing stream data

Tags: h.264

I am reading data from server in h264 format, it write successfully in a .h264 file when we include `UINT8 u8NAL[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};`. 
but when we comment `//UINT8 u8NAL[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};` .h264 file store data but we can not see data on Vlc or Qt.

```
 UINT8 u8NAL[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};
        char name1[100], name2[100];
        _snprintf(name1, 99, "D:\\sizeH264_%p.txt", threadArgs->clientHandle);
        _snprintf(name2, 99, "D:\\dataH264_%p.h264", threadArgs->clientHandle);

    fp = fopen(name1, "w");
    fpFrames = fopen(name2, "wb");

        fwrite(u8NAL, 4, 1, fpFrames);
        fwrite(threadArgs->tmpStreamParams->spsData, threadArgs->tmpStreamParams->spsDataSize, 1, fpFrames);
```

Comment: H.264 spec and its Annex B have the answer. It's free to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 0 0 1 its a header part of a h264 frame, so in short player can know where I have to start and where to stop, that's way we have to give this hex data to every starting point of frame.

And ya its only require when you store data, otherwise you can give direct frame to player.